# Can I get off the train or discontinue my journey before reaching the destination station?

Tags: trains, india, indian-railways

I have booked my ticket for Kanpur to Guwahati. Can I get off at New Jalpaiguri?

Comment: @pnuts: some stations in some countries have ticket checks at exit and don't allow this (ISTR that there are some stations like this in Britain)

Comment: @Max In india you are allowed to get down the train in the middle even though there are exit checks sometimes.

Comment: I only know of one ticket check at an exit in Sweden and that's because that station has an 12 € fee because it's privately owned. If you loose your ticket you'll have to pay 12 € extra.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can get down.  There are no ticket checks at Indian stations, nor is there any reason for them, since there are no crazy promotions that make it cheaper to travel 200 kms to destination X instead of 100 kms to destination Y.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can get down in the middle. There are ticket checks at the exit sometimes (rarely though). But it is okay if you get down your train in the middle of your journey and you donot need to pay extra fares.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can get down. I did this last month. My ticket was from Delhi to Kalka and I got down at Chandigarh. I was a part of the "random exit check" but they didnt create any fuss that says it was all legal.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can, but not recommended.

You should inform the TTE/TC before doing so.
The reason is after you leave if any illegal activity occurs, then they can suspect you. Then it will be your responsibility that you are not attached to it.

So the better option always informs the TTE/TC.

Comment: Why would "they" suspect someone of illegal activity **because** they were not on the train when it was committed? That does not compute at all.

Comment: Some peooles experienced this, thats why this is my suggestion. Now its upto the passenger.