# Need to disembark from train one station past what's shown on the ticket in India

Tags: trains, tickets, south-india, train-stations

My train ticket is from Gwalior to Yesvantpur but can I get off at the next station, Banasawadi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get off the train or discontinue my journey before reaching the destination station?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37468/can-i-get-off-the-train-or-discontinue-my-journey-before-reaching-the-destinatio)

Comment: Banasawadi appears to be after Yesvantpur, not before it.  http://searchmytrain.com/trains-from/gwalior/to/yesvantpur-jn

Comment: Ahh, I'd read it as 'next station' from where he is.

Answer (score 3):

Not without getting a ticket to cover your journey.

In food terms, it'd be like paying for 6 meals and just taking the 7th. It's not allowed.  Similarly, if your ticket is valid from A to B, continuing on to C is NOT on the ticket's terms.

You might get away with it if you stayed on, and played dumb ("oh I fell asleep and missed my stop") but if there's checks or gates, you're going to get caught.

Comment: @pnuts: I have realized that many train conductors in Norway don't speak Norwegian, but did you really find one not speaking English?

Comment: Don't worry, it is a common problem for Norwegians as well, since at least the suburban trains in Norway often have a rather odd and complex stopping pattern. Since the time table change in December 2014, the departure boards for sububrban trains around Oslo don't even try to list the stations, at which the train stops. You have to check the map using the train's line number yourself. I doubt that this has made anything easier.